# Abelian group, invariant and p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

For an abelian group $G$ I have shown that
$$
G=Z(p^{l_1})\times...\times Z(p^{l_r})\Rightarrow G^p\cong Z(p^{l_1-1})\times...\times Z(p^{l_r-1}) \, \text{and ord} (G/G^p)=p^r.
$$

A $p$-group $G$ is defined by the fact that for $p$ prime, for all $a\in G$ there exists exponents $n(a)\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\text{ord}(a)=p^{n(a)}$.

Why does it follow from the above that the number $r$ of cyclical factors is an invariant of the $p$-group $G$?

//edit: Why does it follow that the number of non-trivial factors in $G^{p^l}$ is invariant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of $G/G^p$ is independent of any way of expressing $G$ as a product of subgroups and so  $p^r$ and hence $r$ is an invariant.

Comment: When you mean independent of any way of expressing $G$ as a product of subgroups, you mean independent of the different $l_i$ right? Because the number of cyclic factors is important or do I get that wrong? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, it is a property of the group which assumes nothing about the $l_i$.

Comment: thank you and just one last question - why is it true for a $p$-group $G$ and not just for the $G$ that is defined in the beginning?

Comment: Your $G$ is a p-group so I am not really sure what you mean. (You can define similar invariants for a general finite abelian group.)

Comment: Ah ok, it is a $p$-group because for all $a= a_1,...,a_r \in G$ there is a $n$ with $a^n=(1,1,...,1)$ right? But writing it down I don't really see how to come to this conclusion...

Comment: Just let $n$ be $p$ to the power of the largest of the $l_i$.

Comment: Ah your right, or $n=p^{l_1\cdot... \cdot l_r}$ right?

Comment: Yes, you could use this much larger power if you wished

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: I'm pleased to be of help

Comment: Can I just ask you this last thing: Why does it follow that the number of non-trivial factors in $G^{p^l}$ is invariant?

Comment: $G^{p^l}$ is just another $p$-group and so the invariant result applies to it as well

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't that just mean that the number of factors is invariant? Why also the number of non-trivial factors? Please excuse me if these questions are just too trivial...

Comment: The trivial factors are always completely ignored. This is similar to the expression of numbers as products - if we used trivial factors (i.e. 1) then we would have infinitely many possibilities E.G. $15=3\times5\times1\times1\times1 ...$ with as many $1$s as we like.

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

If it was not, you would have that $G = C_{p^{a_1}}\times C_{p^{a_2}}\times ...\times C_{p^{a_k}}$, and also $G = C_{p^{b_1}}\times ... \times C_{p^{b_s}}$, with $k \ne s$. Then, you would have that the elements of order $p$ in the first presentation are exactly $p^k-1$, and in the second presentation there are $p^s-1$ such elements. Since $k \ne s$, $p^k-1 \ne p^s-1$; however, the two products of cyclic groups are two presentations of the same abelian group, and are thus isomorphic. This leads to contradiction, and so the number of cyclic factors is an invariant for presentation.